# Optional/Anonymous user in ASP.NET Core authentication should resolve to null in DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, dependency-injection

I have an endpoint in my ASP.NET Core (.NET v7) project that should be accessible for authenticated users, as well as anonymous (unauthenticated) users. Depending on their authentication status, the endpoint operates differently. In my other (auth-only) services, I inject a scoped custom class `User`. In the anonymous case, that class should resolve to `null`.

```cs
// In production would lookup user from DB if not-anonymous
builder.Services.AddScoped<User>(services => {
    if (User.IsAuthenticated())
        return new User(/* ... */);
    else return null;
});

// endpoint registration
app.MapGet("/echo", (User? authedUser) => authedUser == null ? "Anonymous" : "Authed").RequireAuthorization().AllowAnonymous();
```

The issue is, that the DI implementation factory for `User` will return `null` (which is what I want), but on anonymous service invocation the DI will throw an exception that no instance for `User` is registered (because it resolved to `null`).

Whats the proper way to achieve this, i.e. inject `null` for the nullable parameter `User? authedUser` for anonymous requests?

Answer (score 1):

I would argue against this. The DI Container should *never* allow to return `null` in the first place, because [services should not be optional](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/#optional-dependencies).

Reason that you want this behavior is that you are injecting runtime data (i.e. your `User` instance) into the object graph. [This is a code smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/) and should, imo, be prevented.

Instead, define an abstraction that allows retrieval of this instance when it is required, e.g.:

```cs
public interface IUserProvider
{
    User CurrentUser { get; }
}

// In production would lookup user from DB if not-anonymous
public class DbUserProvider : IUserProvider
{
    public User CurrentUser => User.IsAuthenticated()
        ? new User(/* ... */)
        : null;
}
```

Comment: "Injecting runtime data is a code smell" goes against all ASP.NET core docs and examples. I give you your own opinion, but this is shurely not something the .NET community agrees upon.

Comment: " goes against all ASP.NET core docs and examples. " That's a pretty strong statement. I've been actually involved in several design discussions with Microsoft during the time ASP.NET Core was still in beta and there are many places during the design process where Microsoft moved away from injecting runtime data directly into their own components, because of the problems that it caused.